# How to group list items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Android's built-in profiles configuration activity contains list with groups:

[image: profiles activity]

Wondering how it is made? Is `ListActivity` with `ExpandableListView` or something else?

I want to build something like that where one group would be always static (could be filled in from XML for example), while the other group would be dynamic (data comes from DB or remote service). What would fit the best for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Headers you can check http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/09/separating-lists-with-headers-in.html

If you want to add custom headers and footers....I can post that code too.......
List I created with grouping and headers and footers looks like this......:

[image: I created this list:]